# Android Canvas Drawline method - what units and where is it documented?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm writing some code that needs to draw some Canvas class drawing primitives consistently on devices with many different DPI's and screen resolutions.    But I can't seem to find what units the *drawLine()* method's points are in.

It doesn't say in the canvas class documentation:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine(float, float, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint))

On S.O. This poster thinks it's in px:
[how to draw lines with drawLine method in multiple density screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188661/how-to-draw-lines-with-drawline-method-in-multiple-density-screens)

... and [the answerer to this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908486/devide-independence-for-canvas-class-drawing-primitives) did some experiments and determined that the units varied according to a setting in the manifest!

I also looked in Google's [Canvas and Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) documentation and the word "units" doesn't even appear there.

What units are the canvas drawing primitives like *drawLine()* in and where does Google/Android officially document this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **pixels**. As with all the Canvas graphical functions (`drawXYZ()`).
Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Mostly because it's all about drawing on a Bitmap.
And a Bitmap  measure unit is the **pixel**.

Comment: I read that document and I didn't see any place where they said the **units** are in px.   They use the _the word_ "pixels" but only in a generic context to mean a point drawn on a display.  What did you see to suggest they meant it as the px unit? (i.e., as opposed to dp, sp, etc)

Comment: It's always talking about **pixels**. It **never mentions other units**. And it begins with: `The Canvas class holds the "draw" calls. To draw something, you need 4 basic components: A Bitmap to hold the pixels`. Therefore, it should be clear that it's all in pixels. Also because a Bitmap  measure unit is the **pixel**.

Comment: It doesn't mention **any** units.  Android doesn't have a unit called "pixels"; it has a unit called "px".   You're assuming that 1 px = 1 pixel, which is not unreasonable but  one of the links I mention in my OP said otherwise.   I looked at the BitMap class [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html] documentation and it also doesn't mention units, but since bitmaps are scalable I don't think we can **assume** that a bitmap pixel reliably equals 1 px (i.e., that 10 pixels takes up 1/48th of a 480 pixel-wide display).

Comment: Well... does it take a genius to understand that **px** is the short for **p**i**x**el? Are you kidding me? It's like saying that `in and inch` are two different units. Or `dp and dip`. Or `mm and millimeter`... http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/ I guess you don't have clear the difference between dp and px.

Comment: Android framework engineer here. It's pixels. The `px` unit is physical display pixels.